# Segmentation Fault when running 3 threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault

So I am creating 3 threads. 1 to read input from the user 1 to do some string manipulation, and 1 to write to the command prompt.

I have set up some `cout` statements to see where I am getting an error. I can see I am getting the error sometime after I create the threads.

I think it has to be something with which thread is executed first. I want the `readerThread` function to run first then the `converterThread` and finally the `writerThread`. I have been looking around for some way to implement more logic on these to restrict the order in which the threads run and can't find any.

Anyways here is my code:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int counter = 0;
vector<string> readBuffer;
vector<string> writeBuffer;
int main (){
    int readerInt,writerInt,converterInt;
    pthread_t reader,writer,converter;
    cout << "BEFORE"<<endl;
    readerInt = pthread_create(&reader, NULL,readerThread,NULL);
    converterInt = pthread_create(&converter,NULL,converterThread,NULL);
    writerInt = pthread_create(&writer,NULL,writerThread,NULL);
    cout << "AFTER" << endl;

    pthread_join(reader,NULL);
    pthread_join(converter,NULL);
    pthread_join(writer,NULL);

    return 0;
}
void * readerThread(void *unused){
    while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    string readLine;
    getline(cin,readLine);
    counter++;
    readBuffer.push_back(readLine);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
void * converterThread(void *unused){
    while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if(readBuffer.size() > 0){
        replace(readBuffer[counter-1].begin(),readBuffer[counter-1].end(),' ','%');
        writeBuffer.push_back(readBuffer[counter-1]);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
void * writerThread(void *unused){
    while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    cout << writeBuffer[counter-1] << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a [readers-writers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers–writers_problem) problem. Consult your nearest browser and fireup the Google, the answer should be waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `writerThread` thread starts the job before the data arrived and you access:

```
cout << writeBuffer[counter-1] << endl;
```

when `counter` is still `0`. You should check the size of `writeBuffer` before access.

`counter` variable is not always valid for `writeBuffer`. It happens when data is in `readBuffer`, but is not yet processed by `converterThread`.

You could remove `counter` variable usage and improve data structures for `readBuffer` and `writeBuffer`. Use [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) to create queue for data conversion. One queue `readBuffer` for read data and one `writeBuffer` queue for processed results. Use push/pop methods.

Comment: Alright, now I am getting the error of it seems to keep looping my `readerThread` function. Doesn't seem like its unlocking. If it is then it gets relocked before the other functions can run.

Comment: @droly96 If segmentation fault is fixed you could play with `sleep(1)` before mutex lock and debug your threads to see what is wrong.